# Understand MySQL deadlock log from InnoDB engine status

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Yesterday on my production I got deadlock related issue for my application,

I took the InnoDB engine status to check the which query generated the deadlock, but I am not able to understand why this is generated.

There were 2 threads running at same time.

- 1st thread tries to execute query `replace into aggregate` from `temp table`
- 2nd thread tries `delete record from aggregate`

Can someone please help me how can I reproduce the same issue, or what causes this issue.

Below is the engine status

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-06-27 03:23:08 0x20ec
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 82199210, ACTIVE 59 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 16 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 618 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 94048, OS thread handle 13292, query id 1096831619 localhost 127.0.0.1 cpro Sending data
DELETE aggr FROM aggregate aggr INNER JOIN product p ON aggr.product_fk=p.product_pk WHERE p.id=2 AND date BETWEEN '2018-04-27 00:00:00' AND '2018-06-26 23:59:59.999'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 45178 page no 57766 n bits 576 index UNIQUE_aggregate of table `data`.`aggregate` trx id 82199210 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 447 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 3; hex 8fc49b; asc    ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000000d; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 6172726976616c73; asc arrivals;;
 3: len 4; hex 0000803f; asc    ?;;
 4: len 6; hex 00001a2b5ff2; asc    +_ ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 82197992, ACTIVE 499 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
2251 lock struct(s), heap size 237776, 30436 row lock(s), undo log entries 24811
MySQL thread id 94049, OS thread handle 8428, query id 1096943836 localhost 127.0.0.1 cpro Creating sort index
replace into aggregate SELECT  date, PRODUCT_FK, DATA_POINT, LOS, SUM(`HOUR`) FROM aggregate_temp GROUP BY date, PRODUCT_FK, DATA_POINT, LOS
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 45178 page no 57766 n bits 576 index UNIQUE_aggregate of table `data`.`aggregate` trx id 82197992 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 447 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 3; hex 8fc49b; asc    ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000000d; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 6172726976616c73; asc arrivals;;
 3: len 4; hex 0000803f; asc    ?;;
 4: len 6; hex 00001a2b5ff2; asc    +_ ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 45178 page no 57766 n bits 576 index UNIQUE_aggregate of table `data`.`aggregate` trx id 82197992 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 447 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 3; hex 8fc49b; asc    ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000000d; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 6172726976616c73; asc arrivals;;
 3: len 4; hex 0000803f; asc    ?;;
 4: len 6; hex 00001a2b5ff2; asc    +_ ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 82207138
Purge done for trx's n:o < 82207138 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2996
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 281885670630400, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
```

Comment: In 2nd thread when you try to delete record from aggregate, does you somehow manipulate also on Product table? There is product_fk related in the 2nd select query. Do you have cascades set on?

Comment: @soulcoder we are not manipulating anything on product table, as in both query delete query uses join from product table, and insert query has product_fk column only.

Comment: @soulcoder that's true, this means product table is already locked by some other process right ?

Answer (score 0):

it locked when execute sql.

look this example.

delete sql will delete record 1 and 3, and replace sql will update 3 and 1.

if the execute sequence like this:

1. tr1 delete record 1.
2. tr2 replace record 3.
3. tr1 try delete record 3 and wait tr2 release lock.
4. tr2 try replace record 1 and detect dead lock.

your delete and replace involve too may records, it may occurs situation above.